# Angular Material Flex MediaObserver Subscribed Twice

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am using Material Flex Layout for detection of screen size.But I get subscribed result twice.The Same Code at another Angular project results fine.

```
constructor(
    public mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {
     mediaObserver.media$.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      if ( change.mqAlias == 'xs') {

        console.log('xsA');
      }else  if ( change.mqAlias == 'sm') {
        console.log('xsB');
      }else{
        console.log('xsC');
      }

    });
}
```

This is my code .

Comment: Is this a component or a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say why you get two emissions with the code you provided. But as a workaround you can use rxjs [distinctUntilKeyChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilkeychanged)  operator;

```js
constructor(public mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {
  mediaObserver.media$.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged('mqAlias'))
    .subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      if (change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
        console.log('xsA');
      } else if (change.mqAlias == 'sm') {
        console.log('xsB');
      } else {
        console.log('xsC');
      }
    });
}
```

Also, I found following issues which might be related;

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/504

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1059

Comment: In my one project my code is working fine.But for other it doesn't .

Comment: It may be because of a lot of different reasons such as; browser, library versions, application itself or it might just be a bug, imho. It is hard to say more without extensively debugging the issue. If you can reproduce the problem on stackblitz or in a github repo I would like to investigate it.